# Executing a command with execvpe in C

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, pipe

For a project, I'm supposed to pipe the output of a command to my C program (called execute), which will then execute that command.

For example, running this:
`echo ls -lR /usr | ./execute`, will take the output (`ls -lR /usr`) and pass it into my C program which will then execute `ls -lR /usr`.

According to the directions, I'm supposed to use `execvpe()` to do the actual execution of the program, however I can't find any documentation that makes sense, nor can I get it to work without getting these errors:

```
execute.c: In function ‘main’:
execute.c:98: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getenv’
execute.c:98: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
execute.c:106: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘execvpe’
```

My professor said that I have to `#include <unistd.h>`, and `<stdio.h>` which I did, parse the input to my program (which I did), and then do this:

```
int main(void) {
    char *path;
    path = getenv("PATH");
    char *envp[] = {path, NULL};
    // the initialized array below could change normally.
    // below is just an example
    char *tests = {"ls", "-lR", NULL};
    int ret = execvpe("ls", tests, envp);
    if(ret == -1) { printf("error\n"); }
    return 0;
}
```

He then stated that execvpe should find the path correctly and execute everything. But no matter what I keep getting these warnings. Running the program and ignoring the warnings immediately seg faults. Does anyone know how `execvpe` works or how I can fix this?

Comment: If you look at the man pages, you can see the type of your arguments are wrong (eg, 2nd argument is `char* const [ ]`, you have `char *`).  Also `tests` is not a `char *`, it is a `char* [ ]`.  The man pages also tells you exactly what #include to use.

Comment: Not every system provides `execvpe()` — Mac OS X does not, for example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm using ssh on a linux server that has it, I'll look more at the man pages, and take Apprentice's advice on the char const.

Answer (score 5):

This code should work, assuming your system has `execvpe()` at all:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char *path = getenv("PATH");
    char  pathenv[strlen(path) + sizeof("PATH=")];
    sprintf(pathenv, "PATH=%s", path);
    char *envp[] = {pathenv, NULL};
    char *tests[] = {"ls", "-lR", NULL};
    execvpe(tests[0], tests, envp);
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to execute \"%s\"\n", tests[0]);
    return 1;
}
```

<sup>*Updated to format `PATH=$PATH` in the environment.*</sup>

It fixes the compilation error on `tests`, uses `tests[0]` as the command name to `execvpe()`; it reports the error on standard error; it includes the name of the command that was not executed; it returns a failure status (non-zero) when exiting; it notes that `execvpe()` only returns if it fails so it isn't necessary to test what its return status is.  It does not include the system error message in the error message, but you could modify the code to include `<errno.h>` and `<string.h>` and use `errno` and `strerror()` to report that information too.

Comment: This works..ish. Unfortunately doing the test case `echo which ls | ./execute` results in `which: no ls in ((null))`. I guess it has to do with the envp pointer and I was told to make path be "PATH=" then append getenv("PATH") with strcat. This gives me a seg fault though. Any ideas on how I could basically get the string: "PATH=getenv("PATH")" without a segfault?

Comment: @Alex: hmm, yes…the code should have set `PATH=$PATH` in the environment, and now it does.  Not doing that shouldn't have affected the operation of the code in the answer; `execvpe()` uses the environment of the calling program, not the environment set in the `envp`, at least AFAIK.  You must be testing a different program, one which actually reads its standard input for a command and then splits that up and tries to execute the command and arguments.  Often, I'd use `snprintf()`, but I just allocated exactly the right amount of space (because `sizeof("PATH=")` counts the trailing null).